# More efficient way of creating dictionaries or a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe I'm filtering and summing. After summing and filtering, I'd like to get my results into a format like so, with the values I've calculated.

```
     Cat1   Cat2 Cat3
 Dog1
 Dog2
 Dog3
```

To get it in that format, I was going to create a set of dictionaries and then convert it back to a dataframe (note I have not included the dataframe creation in my script yet, just the dictionaries). Looping through dictionaries worked fine on a sample subset, but with the real deal, it's taking ages. How can I speed it up?

```
 bigdictionary = {}
 for column1 in df.iloc[:,0:200]:
     cat = column1
     bigdictinary[cat] = {}
     for column2 in df.iloc[:,762:1000]:
         dog = column2
         filterdf = df[df[cat] > 0]
         sumdf = filterdf[dog].sum()
         bigdictionary[cat][dog] = sumdf
```

The hold-up truly seems to be with the dictionary creation, as I don't have a problem if I don't assign to a dictionary.  So, is there a better way to store my values and still get the output format I want?

edit: Here is what my data looks like currently.

```
Index,Thing1,Thing2,Thing3,Thing4,OtherThing1,OtherThing2,OtherThing3
0,1841,0,0,1841,1841,0,1841
1,1195,1195,1195,1195,0,1195,1195
2,318,318,0,318,318,0,318
3,0,0,0,1247,1247,0,1247
4,2170,2170,0,2170,2170,0,2170
5,2049,2049,0,2049,2049,0,2049
6,5920,5920,0,5920,5920,0,5920
7,0,2501,0,0,0,2501,2501
```

Comment: You use `column` to go over both the loops. You probably want to change that to avoid any possible confusion.

Comment: Can you give snippet of your data so we know how to create the result that you want?

Comment: Just updated--let me know if it didn't fit the bill.